# InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In controller i was wrote this,
[HttpGet]
[Route("getregistrationdetails/{accountid}")]

and getting error near the route and calling a using RouteAttribute = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RouteAttribute; and run the code getting the below error:

```
AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: VGL.ClassLibrary.Registration.Repository.IRegistrationRepository Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: VGL.ClassLibrary.Registration.Repository.RegistrationRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'VGL.ClassLibrary.Registration.Repository.RegistrationRepository'.)
```

Here is configuration method:

```
 public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();



        services.AddScoped<IRegistrationRepository, RegistrationRepository>();
        
        //services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql().AddDbContext<RegistrationContext>(options =>
        //options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

        //services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
        //    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0)
        //    .AddNewtonsoftJson(opt => opt.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);

        //services.AddJsonMultipartFormDataSupport();

        //-----------------------------------code for log4net----------------------------------------------
        services.AddSingleton(provider =>
        {
            var service = provider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Logger>>();
            return new Logger(service);
        });
        var logger = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<Logger>();


        logger.Log("Startup.ConfigureServices called");
```

My Controller:

```
 public class RegistrationController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly RegistrationContext regContext;
    private readonly IRegistrationRepository iregrepository;
    private readonly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment whost;



        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        public string dbconstr;
        InfoLogger _objInfoLogger;

        public RegistrationController(RegistrationContext context, IConfiguration Configure, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment host1)
        {
            _objInfoLogger = new InfoLogger();
            regContext = context;
            Configuration = Configure;
            dbconstr = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            this.whost = host1;

             iregrepository = new RegistrationRepository(dbconstr, whost, _objInfoLogger);
        }


    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getregistrationdetails/{accountid}")]
    
    public object Getregistrationdetails(int accountid)
    {
        try
        {
            _objInfoLogger.Info("Started call getregistrationdetails/" + accountid.ToString());
            var products = iregrepository.getregistrationdetails(accountid);
            _objInfoLogger.Info(" Result -- getregistrationdetails/" + Environment.NewLine + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(products));
            return new OkObjectResult(products);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Helper.SendSlackExceptionMsg($"Error from Login details: hello", "LoginDetails");
            Helper.SendSlackEventMsg($"Error from Login details: hello");
            Helper.LogException(ex);
            _objInfoLogger.Info(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }


}
```

Here is My Repository:

```
 public class RegistrationRepository : IRegistrationRepository
{
    private readonly Registrationclasscontext regstContext;
    public string connectionString;
    private readonly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment whost;
    string db_constring = "";


    private static readonly RegionEndpoint bucketRegion = RegionEndpoint.APSouth1;

    InfoLogger _objInfoLogger;
    private string dbconstr;

    

    // private VGL.Middleware.Registration.Controllers.InfoLogger objInfoLogger;

    public RegistrationRepository(string dbconstr, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment host1, InfoLogger objInfoLogger)
    {
        db_constring = dbconstr;
        Registrationclasscontext context = new Registrationclasscontext(dbconstr);
        regstContext = context;
        connectionString = dbconstr;
        this.whost = host1;
        _objInfoLogger = objInfoLogger;
    }



    public async Task<object> getregistrationdetails(int accountid)
    {
        _objInfoLogger.Info("Calling of DB function  public.fn_get_employees_dummy(" + accountid + ")");
        var pt = regstContext.getregistrationdetails.FromSqlRaw("SELECT * from public.fn_get_employees_dummy(" + accountid + ")");
        return pt.ToList();
    }

 
}
```

Comment: Looks to me that the error is not related to the route. It's trying to construct a service from DI and a service there in the dependency chain expects a string in its constructor (which the DI container can't guess what it should be)

Comment: @juunas added complete code

Comment: Your RegistrationRepository expects a string in its constructor. The dependency injection is unable to construct because it does not know what to put there. You need to modify your service registrations in Startup class' ConfigureServices method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is unreadable, weird naming/casing conventions etcetc.

Let's start:

- Add ApiController attribute
- AddRoute attribute above controller
- Use consitent casing
- Use clean method names
- Use clear variable names (clean code)
- Use DI
- Use ILogger
- Refactoring

This will make it readable for others to help you(i did this in a scratch file so just use it as guide line)

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddScoped<IRegistrationRepository, RegistrationRepository>();
        
        services.AddEntityFrameworkNpgsql()
                .AddDbContext<RegistrationContext>( 
                    options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);
    }
}
```

**RegistrationsController.cs**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/registrations")]
public class RegistrationController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IRegistrationRepository _repository;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public RegistrationController(ILogger logger, RegistrationRepository repository, IConfiguration config, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _repository = repository ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));
        _config = config ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));
        _env = env ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(env));
    }


    [HttpGet("details/{accountid}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetDetails(int accountid)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.Info("Getting registration details..");
            var products = await _repository.GetDetailsAsync(accountid);

            return Ok(products);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Something went wrong");
            return StatusCode(500, "Something went wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

**RegistrationRepository.cs**

```
public class RegistrationRepository : IRegistrationRepository
{
    private readonly RegistrationContext _context;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public RegistrationRepository(ILogger<RegistrationContext> logger, RegistrationContext context, IConfiguration config)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        _config = config ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));
    }

    public async Task<List<Registration>> GetDetailsAsync(int accountid)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("getting details");

        return await _context.Registrations
                .FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * from public.fn_get_employees_dummy({accountid})")
                .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Try work from there

Comment: Thank you @Tobias Lie-Atjam

Comment: No problem, hope it helped!